# Beginners Erlang - hello_world

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I have a similar problem to the this:

```
-module(hello).
-export([hello_world/0]).

hello_world() -> io:fwrite("hello, world\n").
```

Result:

```
(hello_world@PC)8> hello:hello_world().
** exception error: undefined function hello:hello_world/0
(hello_world@PC)9>
```

but the instructions

"The way to fix that:

Go to: 
Run configurations
--Erlang
Select tab:
--Environment
then
--Select
check
-- Path
Apply and run."

do not solve my problem.

Is it perhaps my software, because getting hold of some of it was quite troublesome. I have Erlang 5.10.1 R16B with Erlide plug-in (version 0.9.0.201010061109) for Eclipse 4.2.2?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you compile the module `c(hello`)?

Comment: Where did you find the instructions you were following?

Answer (score 3):

Did you compile your `hello.erl`?

```
c(hello).
```

After that you get a `hello.beam` file, and then you can try to execute:

```
hello:hello_world().
```

In the directory with the `hello.beam` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your editor window, right click and choose `Run As->Erlang application`. This will open a shell on a node where your module is compiled and loaded and you can execute `hello:hello_world()`.

When editing the file, it will be compiled and reloaded automatically after save. You don't need to open a new console, just reuse the original one.